# closed source front end. analyze sql server db recent inserts as i add records to front end

Tags: sql-server

I need to write code that can automate some data entry into sql server 2012.  The closed source front end touches a lot of tables when entering sales orders. If i could easily see what tables where inserted / updated after i input a test record into the front end it would help me know what inserts and update statments i needed to simulate what the front end was doing.  is there an easy way to analyze the tables impacted? im running sql server 2012 and management studio 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a trace using [SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).  This will capture all interactions with the database based on what you set for filters.

Comment: this seems exactly what i need buy it says server 2016 or later.  I'll keep reading.

Comment: You don't need to buy it.  It comes with SQL Server if you have the tools (if you have SSMS, then you have profiler).  The message says it's in 2016 but will NOT be in later versions.  It works for 2012 just fine.